# Why use GeoServer or Tegola to generate vector tiles from PostGIS rather than ST_AsMVT?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, vector-tiles, tegola

I don't have much experience generating vector tiles dynamically. Instead I use Tippecanoe.

I'm looking at generating tiles from PostGIS and see at least three options:

- PostGIS + Geoserver (with vector tiles extension)
- PostGIS + Tegola
- PostGIS, using its own native [ST_AsMVT](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVT.html) function.

So: What is the benefit of using an additional layer on top of PostGIS rather than its own direct support for vector tile generation?

Comment: If you have Geoserver, I would suggest trying it out - I would go that route personally, but we don't have the need for them...I think the PostGIS tiles are for those who won't be able to use Geoserver, but some may suggest otherwise...

Comment: If you use plain ST_AsMVT you must write yourself the SQL that selects the correct vectors for tiles at each zoom level. Handling that scale dependent stuff is probably easier with ready made servers.